# TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found in python 3

Tags: python, bioinformatics

I was trying to an take RNA sequence as input and get its respective codons as output.

For example:

Input: `AUGGGAACUUCACUACGUAAAUAG`

Output: Codons are: `AUG, GGA, ACU, UCA, CUA, CGU, AAA, UAG`

I coded like this in Python 3.8:

```
rna = input("Enter the RNA sequence:")
list1 = []
rna = list(rna)

for i in range(len(rna)):
    list2 = []
    list2.append(rna[i : i + 3 : 3])
    liststr = "".join(list2)
    list1.append(liststr)

 print(list1)
```

But, I am getting the error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found`. What is the issue with this code?

Comment: Note that often with real biological sequence data, you need to consider different up to six different reading frames

Comment: This error happens because `list2` is a list-of-lists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're overcomplicating things. You just need to maintain one list, and walk through the string three characters at a time. There's no need to transform a string into a list, or vice versa.

```py
rna = input("Enter the RNA sequence:")
result = []
for i in range(0, len(rna), 3):
    result.append(rna[i:i+3])
print(result)
```

With the sample input, this produces:

```py
['AUG', 'GGA', 'ACU', 'UCA', 'CUA', 'CGU', 'AAA', 'UAG']
```

Comment: One could even build `result` with a list comprehension.  `result = [rna[i : i + 3] for i in range(0, len(rna), 3)]`

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `list2` is a list of lists.

But `str.join` doesn't work on lists of lists. Consider a minimal example:

```
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>> ''.join(a)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

You need to join each list into a string. Something like:

```
list2 = [''.join(lst) for lst in list2]
```